# Wordpress function to add text warning on every pages

Tags: plugins, functions, custom-field, text, warnings

How to add a function to show a text (without JS) in every pages on Wordpress?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Show us what you have tried, where and why you failed, and what your specific problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want it to appear?

this function will put something before, or after, the content of each page.

```
function rt_before_after($content) {
    $beforecontent = 'This goes before the content.';
    $aftercontent = 'And this will come after.';
    $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;

    return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'rt_before_after');
```

If you want it somewhere in particular let me know where you want and I'll provide other options.